# Perl DBI array - split

Tags: perl, split, dbi

I'm trying to split the results of a mysql query using perl and DBI module. Here's my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use DBI;

$dbh = DBI->connect('DBI:mysql:host', 'user', 'password'
                   ) || die "Could not connect to database: $DBI::errstr";


$sql = "SELECT * FROM users;";
$sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$sth->execute or die "SQL Error: $DBI::errstr\n";
while (@row = $sth->fetchrow_array) {

my @value1 = split(".",@row);
my $domain = $value1[1];

print "$domain\n";

}

$dbh->disconnect();
```

The query result is similar to: **username.domain**
So I want to split the result with "." to show only the "domain" but it return me an error: 
Use of uninitialized value $domain in concatenation (.) or string ...

Thanks!

Comment: `@row` in scalar context evaluates to the number of elements in `@row`. That is what you are splitting. Which field do you want to split? The first one? That's `$row[0]`.

Comment: Add `use strict; use warnings;` to the top of every Perl script you write, just beneath the shebang, and lose the `-w` flag. This will help you avoid lots of errors and will make troubleshooting vastly easier.

Comment: `"."` in split is regex, and `select *` accompanied by `fetchrow_array` is, to put it mildly, terrible idea.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use warnings;
use DBI;


my $dbh = '';
my $sql = '';
my $sth = '';
my @dbRow= ();


$dbh = DBI->connect('DBI:mysql:host', 'user', 'password'
                   ) || die "Could not connect to database: $DBI::errstr";


$sql = "SELECT * FROM users;";
$sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$sth->execute or die "SQL Error: $DBI::errstr\n";
while (@dbRow = $sth->fetchrow_array) {
    foreach my $dbData (@dbRow)
    {
        print split (/\./,$dbData)->[1]; 
    }
}

$dbh->disconnect();
```

Comment: Areas in need of improvement: Bad formatting. Doesn't compile. Unlikely that more than one field of users row is of the form `user.domain`. `@domain` is poorly named, since only `$domain[1]` is a domain. No explanation of the key problem(s).

Answer (score 4):

Let's walk through your code. With added comments.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
# Always always, start Perl programs with "use strict" and "use warnings".
# I know you have "-w" on the shebang line, but lose that as "use warnings"
# is a more flexible improvement.

use DBI;

# If you "use strict" then you need to declare all of your variables. So
# this line should start "my $dbh = ".
$dbh = DBI->connect('DBI:mysql:host', 'user', 'password'
                   ) || die "Could not connect to database: $DBI::errstr";


$sql = "SELECT * FROM users;";
$sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$sth->execute or die "SQL Error: $DBI::errstr\n";
while (@row = $sth->fetchrow_array) {
    # Code is always easier to follow with good indentation.

    # Several issues here.
    # The first parameter to split() is a regular expression. I recommend
    # always putting it in /.../ so you're not tempted to assume it's a string.
    # In a regex, the dot has a special meaning. It matches any character. To
    # match a literal dot, you need to escape it with a \.
    # The second parameter to split() is a string to split. You can't give it
    # an array (well, you can, but it will use the number of elements in the 
    # array which is probably not what you want!
    my @value1 = split(".",@row);
    my $domain = $value1[1];

    print "$domain\n";

}

$dbh->disconnect();
```

Taking all of those, your code should probably look more like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use DBI;

my $dbh = DBI->connect('DBI:mysql:host', 'user', 'password')
    || die "Could not connect to database: $DBI::errstr";

my $sql = "SELECT * FROM users;";
my $sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$sth->execute or die "SQL Error: $DBI::errstr\n";

while (my @row = $sth->fetchrow_array) {    
    # Assume $row[0] is the value to want to split
    my @value1 = split(/\./, $row[0]);
    my $domain = $value1[1];

    print "$domain\n";
}

$dbh->disconnect();
```

Comment: Since you `use strict;` you have to declare `$sql`, `$sth` and `@row` as you pointed out yourself in your explanation.

Comment: Oops. Yes. Thanks for pointing that out (and thanks to @mpapec for fixing my post).